# How to clear controlled forms in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-redux, state

I'm trying to clear a form in my react-redux component. I know that I should be able to clear them using setState() after a submit, but since I'm receiving all my data as props (via the redux store) is there an easy way to do this within the component itself?

```
class Postform extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            propertyName: ' enter name ',
            footage: ' size in sqft ',
            address: ' full address ',
            price: ' $ 00.00 '
        }   
    }

    onChange =(e)=>{
        this.setState({ [e.target.name] :e.target.value});
    }

    onSubmit = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        const newListing = {
            propertyName: this.state.propertyName,
            footage: this.state.footage,
            address: this.state.address,
            price: this.state.price
        }

        this.props.newProperty(newListing)
// my attempt to reset the state of the form (unsure how to accomplish this?)
        this.setState({
            propertyName: '',
            footage: '',
            address: '',
            price: ''
        })
    };


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="form">
                <h2>Add Listing</h2>
                <form onSubmit = {this.onSubmit}>
                    <div>
                        <label>your listing name</label><br/>
                        <input name="propertyName" type="text" onChange={this.onChange} placeholder={this.state.propertyName} />
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <label>listing size </label><br/>
                        <input name="footage" onChange={this.onChange} placeholder={this.state.footage} />
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <label>listing location </label><br/>
                        <input name="address" onChange={this.onChange} placeholder={this.state.address} />
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <label>desired price </label><br/>
                        <input name="price" onChange={this.onChange} placeholder={this.state.price} />
                    </div>

                    <br/>
                        <button className="submitbtn" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

Postform.propTypes = {
    newProperty: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    new: PropTypes.object
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>({
    listings: state.listings.properties,
    new: state.listings.newListing
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {newProperty})(Postform)
```

I checked around online and found a few solutions. I wanted to see if anyone could tell me based on my code if there would be a preferred way of achieving this?

Here all the different methods I found not sure which I should use based on my component though : https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.7/docs/faq/howtoclear.md/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems valid to me, I would only do the job in a bit 'lazy' manner:

```
this.setState(Object.keys(this.state).forEach(key => this.state[key] = ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { initialize, reset } from 'redux-form';    
dispatch(initialize('formName', {})); // Clear form

// or 

dispatch(reset('formName'));
```

Comment: Please kindly add some guidance to your code only answer, thanks.